# Where to take grubx64.efi file?

Tags: ubuntu, grub, uefi

I suspect, that if I put this file into my `EFI` partition into `/EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi`, I will be able to add entry for this file and it will be seen by bios and my non-bootable Linux partition will start to boot.

I have an access to (virtual) runnable Ubuntu. Where to borrow this file from the system?

Comment: You should create this file yourself using `grub-install` command. This [link](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB/EFI_examples#Lenovo) may show you how.